# Adding a kivy custom widget only adds the first layout

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to add a custom widget for each item in a list.
The first one works fine, but every on following the first, only the first Layout is shown. (yellow square)

I have already tried to add_widget(Builder.load_string the entire Custom Widget, leading to the same result.

The Layout class referenced to the custom widget:

```py
class StockPortfolio(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

The function to add the widgets:

```py
    portfolio_list = [1, 2, 3]

    def add_stock_portfolio(self, layout):
        layout.clear_widgets()
        for i in self.portfolio_list:
            layout.add_widget(StockPortfolio())
```

And the beginning of the custom widget kv:

```
<StockPortfolio@FloatLayout>
    id: stockportfolio
    size_hint: None, None
    height: app.root.height * .18
    width: app.root.width -10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .98, .98, 0, .5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Button:
        background_normal: ''
        background_down: ''
        background_color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        pos: 5, 5
        on_release:
            app.go_screen(4)
            app.load_popup2()
            app.update_current(portfolioticker1.text, portfoliocompany.text)
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos: 5, 5
        size_hint: None, None
        height: app.root.height * .18
        width: app.root.width -10
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .98, .98, .98, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problems

1. In your Kivy App, there are two different classes of `StockPortfolio()`. The one declared in the kv file is a Dynamic Class whereas the other one declared in Python script is a class Rule. Dynamic class does not require an implementation in Python script.
2. `StockPortfolio` objects added are stacked on top of each other.

## Solution

1. In the kv file, change the Dynamic class to class rule by removing `@FloatLayout`.
2. Provide button's size
3. Provide new position for each stock portfolio added into layout.

### Snippets - kv file

```
<StockPortfolio>:
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and explaining the difference between the two classes. I solved it by following your solution and gave the children of my custom widget class a root.pos reference to stop them from stacking on top of each other. Now they are aligned as intended. Thanks!